# Guice inject httpheaders

Tags: guice, dropwizard

We using Dropwizard for our rest api, along with guice for injection. Wanted to know if its possible to inject the http headers. We need to access a particular header value for every api call, within some of the internal classes.

Answer (score 0):

injection of header is not guice specific. That is done by jersey.

(assuming you use DW with jersey)

You can do this:

```
@POST
@Path("/myPath")
@Timed(name = "logEvent")
public Response test(@HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent) {
    return Response.ok(userAgent).build();
}
```

This would inject your "user-agent" header into the jersey annotated resource method.

Hope that helps,

Artur